# Android Notification during app is in background, intent data is empty

Tags: android, notifications

I'm using this code, when the app is in the foreground it was working perfectly. but the notification coming during app is in background Intent does not have any data.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(Constant.device_id,deviceId);
    intent.putExtra(Constant.isFromPush,true);
    intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title_)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                getString(R.string.app_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt( 2000 ) /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: show your SpalshActivity Code.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isFromPush=getIntent().getBooleanExtra(Constant.isFromPush,false);
       String dev="";
               dev=getIntent().getStringExtra(Constant.device_id);
        if (isFromPush){

            Log.e("from push","Yes" +dev);
        }else {
            Log.e("from push","No"+dev);

        }
    }

Comment: let me know if it is working ->

 override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
//place your code here
}

Comment: nope not working, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two type of Payload in case of send-downstream  both are optional.

**data**

This parameter specifies the custom key-value pairs of the message's payload.

**notification**

This parameter specifies the predefined, user-visible key-value pairs of the notification payload.

[https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream][Find More detail here]

When you are in background, FCM will showing notification in system tray based on the info from notification payload. Title, message, and icon which used for the notification on system tray are get from the notification payload.

```
{
  "notification": {
        "title" : "title",
        "body"  : "body text",
        "icon"  : "ic_notification",
        "click_action" : "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
       }
}
```

You need to use **data**  payload  instead of  notification payload ,your issue get resolved .

Here is the example JSON i'm reciving :

```
{
  "to": "FCM registration ID",

   "data": {
     "someData"  : "This is some data",
     "someData2" : "etc"
   }
}
```

Here is my java code.

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

            try {
                JSONObject json = new 
                JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Messages with both notification and data payload:**

A message can also contains both notification and data payload. When these kind of messages are sent, it will be handled in two scenarios depending upon app state (background / foreground). For these message we can use both notification and data keys.

**When in the background** – Apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.

**When in the foreground** – App receives a message object with both payloads available.

Comment: thanks a lot, I was parsing the value only from remoteMessage.getNotification() only.

Answer (score 3):

To Handle intent data when app is in background you need to do something extra.
There should have "data" key in your response to get it in activity. Like,

```
{
"notification": {
    "key_1": "value_1",
    "key_2": "value_2"
 },
"data": {
    "key_1": "value_1",
    "key_2": "value_2"
 },

}
```

And you need to get the values inside your launching activity's onCreate method.
Launching activity is which `<intent-filter>` contains

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Receive data,

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
   //bundle contains all info of "data" field of the notification
}
```

> In background, app receives notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle data payload when the user taps on the notification

Comment: Does your response contain data key?

Comment: Both "notification" and "data" key should have to be in your push message

Comment: Try to handle that intent in activity with `intent filter` `LAUNCHER` By default it takes the `data` from notifications. If you use splash screen, just copy `Intent` into activity where you need that data

Comment: @YaroslavOvdiienko could you please explain with few lines of code. thanks

Comment: Check your manifest, which activity contains android.intent.category.LAUNCHER, then inside of that Activity's onCreate method, get extras using Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
   //bundle contains all info of "data" field of the notification
}
To get key_1 value , it should be getIntent().getExtras().getString("key_1")

Comment: @AvinashAjayPandey https://gist.github.com/yaroslav-android/c60032d496621671f4da8d56c2677cde

Comment: @Exigente05. you saved my day brother. Thanks.
This approach worked for me.